# How should I secure a private rails application from outside users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, security, email

I need to build an application that will only serve people in my workplace. Currently, everyone has a specific company email, which has a unique domain and format.

I created a regular expression that only validates our company email addresses, and configured the application to require email confirmation. This seems like it should be sufficient, unless a malicious person:

1. Finds a flaw in my expression.
2. Finds a way around confirmation.
3. Somehow gets a company email address.

I feel like this isn't secure enough though. Maybe I need to take it one more step, with some kind of pre-approved email list or something?

I'm curious if anyone else has faced this problem. (Most likely.)

Comment: Do you have a company authentication service like LDAP? Otherwise, I'd even go as far and require manual activation of accounts by an administrator.

Comment: What's a per-approved email list? You know there are a lot of apps that use email as their login id, right? I'm not sure what your concern really is.

Comment: IT has our email on a very old version of exchange server. It looks like I could query it, or export it's email list to a CSV.

Comment: Does your company share a network?  If so can't you just limit access to the IP address

Comment: Sorry, I meant pre-approved. I was thinking I could have a database of known company emails I could compare against during login. I'm trying to avoid a fake account/email. I'm really just concerned that our email domain could be "faked" somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I've considered white-listing IP. Everyone wants access via mobile devices though, so I would have to white list all those cell devices. It's a good idea though.

Comment: It's a text field. I don't know what you mean by faking it. Are you talking about sending an initial email?

Comment: I really like KappaNossi's idea. I think maybe I will add an activated boolean to the User model. Then, have an admin user set them to true to activate them. Then I can use user.activated? on them before logging them in.

Comment: Basically, I have a bunch of users with first_last@mycompany.com.
I want to make sure that nobody can sneak around my regex, and create accounts, etc, without a valid company address. e.g, I can't trust that somebody won't find an email domain that works around my regex.

Comment: First choice: Use LDAP to authenticate the user. By the way, why use regex for matching the email address? If you have a specific email address host then compare that part of the email address specifically with that string. Regex should work, but isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution:

This will enable a second level of security:

On the User model, create a `boolean` field called `user_active`.

Then, create an Admin page that will only allow your admins to check/uncheck accounts.

Then, you can call `User.user_active?` before logging your users in.

This makes it much harder for somebody who manages to sneak around your security to access your app.

This would be a pain with tons of users, but if you only have 200 or so, this will work.

Comment: At this point wouldn't you be better off just having an admin area where users are created?